# jQuery: Something wrong with the Event Object?

Tags: jquery

While this works:

`jsfiddle.net/ktnH8/`

This does not:

`jsfiddle.net/ktnH8/1/`

What is the problem with the latter? I only have changed this:

```
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

To this:

```
$('#drop_zone).bind('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
$('#drop_zone).bind('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: Why do you keep logging in with a different account? Log in with the same account and you can comment on your own questions.

Comment: (re quotes, from the OP) "it is just copy-paste failure" - well, I wonder what *other* copy-paste failures are lurking. I don't think we can diagnose without the *actual* code.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid, you're missing some closing quotes `'`.

Also, look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) for the possible `.bind` syntax:

```
.bind( eventType, [ eventData ], handler(eventObject) )
.bind( eventType, [ eventData ], false )
```

You'll have to use `$('#drop_zone').bind('dragover', handleDragOver)`, otherwise `handleDragOver` is interpreted to be the `eventData` parameter, not as the `handler` parameter.